# How to send additional param for connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I use Socket.io
Client:

```
var socket = new io.Socket(null, {port: 8081, ...
```

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(client){ ...
```

Sow actually I try to do multiroom chat app - so how can I pass chat_id or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the same issue and finally decided to go with [Push-It].[1](https://github.com/aaronblohowiak/Push-It)

Documentation is a bit rare, but it's quite easy to use.

Comment: Thank you man   I just use socket.on("connect" ... triger to send technical data